# How to change the color in my slides?

Tags: beamer, color

I am creating my slides by using CambridgeUS theme. The standard color of this theme is red, but I would like to change it into blue. 
Is this possible? How to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

blue is the new red :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


\colorlet{darkred}{blue!80!black}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or use a bluish colour theme:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]